# using Hdirect and idl for win32 com/ole automation

Tags: haskell, com, automation

I’m trying to use hdirect.exe from  [hdirect](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hdirect) with the provided example “Connection.idl” (inside C:\hdirect-0.21.0\comlib) but I received the following error: 
hdirect.exe: ./Connection.hs: commitBuffer: invalid argument (character is not in the code page)

Do you have any clue how can i generate the Haskell file from IDL ?

Comment: Sounds like an error in the file encoding. If you set your locale to e.g. "C" ; does that fix it?

Comment: i'm not sure how to setup this locale under windows environment. i changed it in panelSetting->Regional and Language -> administration-> english. But it did not change anything.

Comment: i suppose i have to install cygwin.